# Node Bull Queue Error: Missing process handler for job type JOB_NAME

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, redis, queue, bull-queue

I am creating node bull queue and passing a dynamic name as an option to the `Queue.add function`

```
myQueue.add(`myJob-${val}`, {
    attempts: 3,
    removeOnFail: true
});
```

I am defining the process name as below for the above job

```
myQueue.process(`myJob-${val}`, async (job, callback) => {
    try {
        console.log('Processing job', job.id, job.data);
        callback();

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

However, I am getting below error

```
Job ID 1 failed Error: Missing process handler for job type myJob-123
```

How to correctly define the `processor` with a dynamic name value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake you are making is passing extra fields in the add method.
Remove the name value from add method everything will work
only two parameters you have to pass while adding a job::--> data and options

```
myQueue.add({dummydatakey:"dummydataval"}, {attempts: 3,removeOnFail: true});
```

**A sample job handler file for your Ref:**

```
const Queue = require('bull'); 

module.exports = {

jobStatusCheckScheduler: async function () {
    console.log('hi')
    // 1. Initiating the Queue
    const statusCheckQueue = new Queue("JobStatusCheck", {
        redis: {
            host: "127.0.0.1",
            port: 6379,
        },
    });

    const options = {            
        attempts: 3,
        removeOnFail: true,
        repeat: {
            every: 10000,
            limit: 5,
        },
    };

    // 2. Adding function in the job
    statusCheckQueue.process(async (job, callback) => {
        try {
            console.log('Processing job', job.id, job.data);
            callback();

        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }).then(() => {
        console.log('suresh')
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })

    // 3. Adding a Job to the Queue
    await statusCheckQueue.add( {user: '1'}, options).then((job) => {
        console.log('suresh first', job.id)
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })

    // 4. Listener
    statusCheckQueue.on("error", (err) => {
        console.log(`Job error ${err}`);
    });

    statusCheckQueue.on("progress", function (job, progress) {
        // A job's progress was updated!
    });

    statusCheckQueue.on("completed", (job, result) => {
        console.log("Job completed", job.data);
    });

    statusCheckQueue.on("failed", function (job, err) {
        // A job failed with reason `err`!
        console.log(`Job not completed failed ${err}`);
    });
}
```

};

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't your 2nd argument to `.add()` be the Job data? The job options you are passing in as the 2nd argument are correct, but they should be third.

Possibly try this instead:

```js
myQueue.add(`myJob-${val}`, { lorem: "ipsum" }, {
    attempts: 3,
    removeOnFail: true
});
```

In cases where I've received that same error of `Missing process handler for job ___` it has been because I have added the job before the processor is running. When that issue is unavoidable increasing the `attempts` (like you did) to a number greater than 1 has fixed it. However, you're passing in those job options as the `data`, so the `attempts` won't affect your queue.